# Cascading Context Menu Explorer CommandStore Missing

Tags: contextmenu, windows-vista, explorer, 7zip, regedit

I'm trying to create a new cascading menu  for the windows context menu but in my registry on Windows Vista I do not have a `CommandStore` Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\` and if I add one it does not work.
For instance if I was to say do this:

```
        Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\Menu]
"MUIVerb"="ZIP"
"SubCommands"="SFX"
"icon"="c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SFX]
@="Compress To Exe"
"icon"="c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\SFX\command]
@=""c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" u -mx9 -sfx -r -t7z "%1.exe" "%~f1""
```

All I get is a menu item called ZIP but no sub menus and an error when clicked.

This will not work, am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this can be done only with Windows 7 (and potentially later versions)